# How to get default view for openstreet map based on markers?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

If all the markers for particular users are all in the USA, then when users opens map, by default map should focus on the USA where all markers are visible, similarly If all marker positions are present in India, then the map should be focused on India when the user opens

Comment: If you have features in a vector source you can fit the view to the source extent after the data has loaded https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-features-forked-n4800q?file=/main.js

Answer (score 0):

```
var extent = vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent();
mapObject.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), {
            maxZoom: 15,
        })
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?